# iOS URL scheme for navigation App?

Tags: ios, gps, url-scheme

I added link from my iOS app to several navigation system using URL Scheme

I didn't find anything for :

- Tomtom
- iGo (igomyway://G[lat];[lon] seem don't work now)
- Copilot
- Viamichelin
- Navmii
- Aponia
- iCoyote
- Mappy

I sent mail to companies / developers but Didn't get any answer.

Someone can help ?

Comment: Can you please provide list of url schemes which you found

Comment: For waze

> waze://?ll=[lat],[lon]&z=10

Answer (score 2):

**TomTom Go**

[In November TomTom added a URL Scheme for TomTom Go](https://discussions.tomtom.com/en/discussion/1118783/url-schemes-for-go-navigation-ios):

`tomtomgo://x-callback-url/navigate?destination={{Latitude}},{{Longitude}}`

Answer (score 0):

TomTom has still not implemented any url scheme/deeplink for their Go app and might never implement one. See this clossed discussion: 
https://discussions.tomtom.com/en/discussion/999005/url-scheme-for-tomtom-go-mobile-ios

Waze uses deeplink urls, check here:
https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/

Other apps you mentioned. If they creators don't provide a url-scheme or deeplink on their site, they probably don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

> > Once I open iGO with this `deeplink`  URL `"igomyway://G47.498562;19.040910`"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Mappy, this is what I found:

> mappy://fr.mappy.com/gps/TRANSPORT/ADDRESS

TRANSPORT:
seems to be able to be replaced by "car" or "car_fastest"

ADDRESS:
Must be replaced with the URL encoded postal address
To use a GPS address, it must be in the form: "LATITUDE, LONGITUDE"
The space after the decimal point seems compulsory.
And everything must also be URL encoded

Example with a postal address:

> mappy://fr.mappy.com/gps/car_fastest/Champ%20de%20Mars%2C%205%20Avenue%20Anatole%20France%2C%2075007%20Paris

Example with a GPS address:

> mappy://fr.mappy.com/gps/car_fastest/48.8583%2C%202.2945

Comment: It is not working, tested on iOS 14, it is only opening Mappy without setting up the address.